# How to decode a JSON with Python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, decode

I am trying to decode a JSON with Python. Here is a little snippet of what the JSON looks like.

```
b'{"success":true,"data":[{"id":26,"name":"A","comment":"","start_time_plan":null,"start_time_actual":"2016-09-13 00:00:00","start_time_delta":null,"start_time_score":null,"start_time_score_achievement":null,"start_time_traffic_light":null,"end_time_plan":null,"end_time_actual":"2016-09-13 00:00:00","end_time_delta":null,"end_time_score":null,"end_time_score_achievement":null,"end_time_traffic_light":null,"status":0,"measure_schedule_revision_id":63,"responsible_user_id":3,"created_time":"2016-09-13 11:29:14","created_user_id":3,"modified_time":"2016-09-21 16:33:41","modified_user_id":3,"model":"Activity"},{"id":27,"name":"B","comment":"","start_time_plan":null,"start_time_actual":"2016-09-13 00:00:00","start_time_delta":null,"start_time_score":null,"start_time_score_achievement":null,"start_time_traffic_light":null,"end_time_plan":null,"end_time_actual":"2016-09-13 00:00:00","end_time_delta":null,"end_time_score":null,"end_time_score_achievement":null,"end_time_traffic_light":null,"status":0,"measure_schedule_revision_id":63,"responsible_user_id":3,"created_time":"2016-09-13 11:29:48","created_user_id":3,"modified_time":"2016-10-16 18:14:36","modified_user_id":1,"model":"Activity"}
```

I am trying to get a hold of `start_time_delta`and `end_time_delta` and produce a little scatter plot. But somehow I can't decode the JSON.

Here is what I do:

```
#falcon api
u = 'https://myurl.com'

#urllib3 + poolmanager for requests
import urllib3
http = urllib3.PoolManager()

import json
r = http.request('GET', u)
json.loads(r.data.decode('utf-8'))

end = json.loads(r.data['end_time_delta'])
start = json.loads(r.data['start_time_delta'])
```

This is the error I get:  byte indices must be integers or slices, not str

How come? And how do I solve the problem?

Comment: Also consider using the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module, which automatically handles pooling and provides a very simple way to parse the JSON returned by a request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are ignoring the return value of `json.loads()` here:

```
json.loads(r.data.decode('utf-8'))
```

You then try to decode the same raw *again* and try to use that as the decoded Python result. Call `json.loads()` *once*, and use the resulting Python dictionary:

```
result = json.loads(r.data.decode('utf-8'))
start = result['data'][0]['start_time_delta']
end = result['data'][0]['end_time_delta']
```

Because top-level dictionary `'data'` key points to a *list* of results, I used `0` to get to the first of those and extract the data you want.

If you need to extract those data points for *every dictionary* in that list, you'd have to use a loop:

```
for entry in result['data']:
    start = entry['start_time_delta']
    end = entry['end_time_delta']
    # do something with these two values, before iterating to the next
```

Comment: Ah...I am such a fool! Thank you! I guess I can now loop through the JSON from `0` to `n`?

Comment: @Rachel: Python loops are foreach constructs, no need to use indices when you can just access the contained elements of a sequence directly.